# Question about Ubuntu installion disk?

Tags: system-installation

how can I make a Ubuntu installation disk? I am planning on to fresh install Ubuntu on a new hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have burn the downloadable .iso file of the desired Ubuntu version onto an empty disc.

[BurningIsoHowto – Tutorial on disc burning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

Answer (score 0):

### Aim higher !

You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) to make bootable USB. I've only been using USB to install Ubuntu and it's been great. It works on most computers.. It only failed me once on a 10 years old machine.

If you already have ubuntu installed somewhere then getting [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) is easy just open a terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type `sudo apt-get unetbootin`. 
Else you can download a windows version from the website.

Bootable USB works the same way as a disk you only need to boot from USB obviously.